# Add task validation still adds a empty task even though field is blank

Tags: javascript

In a tutorial i am following the tutor uses an alert box to validate an empty text field on clicking "Add Task", if there is no task the user gets an alert to tell them to add to the task. I wanted to modify this abit and instead of an alert I wanted to have a message appear under the text field which I have done successfully, however I have noticed that this still adds an blank task to the "Tasks" section of my app.

I have tried to call the removeTask() function so that it removes the blank task, but this didn't work and also I feel this is a hackey way to solve this.

I have tried to add an else statement to the if statement that presents the message and add in the code that would populate the "Tasks" section, but this didn't work too

Not sure what else to try?

```
// ADD TASK FUNCTION

// addTask Function Creation
function addTask(e) {
  if(taskInput.value === '') {
    //alert('Add a Task');
    const addTaskErr = document.getElementById('addTaskError');
    addTaskErr.style.color = 'red';
    addTaskErr.innerHTML = 'Please add a task';
  } else {
    // Creat li Element
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // Add class
    li.className = 'collection-item';
    // Create Text Node and Append to li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
    // Create new link element
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    // Add Class
    link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
    // Add Icon HTML
    link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
    // Append Link To li
    li.appendChild(link);

    // Append li to ul
    taskList.appendChild(li);

    //console.log(li);

    // Store task in Local Storage
    storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInput.value);

    // Clear The Input
    taskInput.value = '';
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Expected Result:

It should only present a message if there is no task typed in the new task text field and if there is, it should not present a message and add the task.

Actual Results:

Even if the new task text field is left empty a new blank task is still being added to the "Task" section of my app on clicking "Add Task".

Please can you guide me on how this would be done and if I need to provide any further information or code?

Thanks

Nav

Comment: Could you add how you call this function, and the HTML involved?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and javascript code, I understood that you're calling function `addTask` with some text when `add` button is clicked. So, I prepared sample `HTML` based upon my understanding. It is similar to the `TODO` list application. You can run the below snippet.

**Why you are getting issue**

Because you're always checking value is initial or not. If value initial then you are directly showing message and also not removing it when task added.

**Below changes I did**

1. Moved error text to the HTML code and read the element into one global variable `addTaskErr`. Initially error text set to hidden and when value is empty then I'm showing this text by setting `display` to empty. 
        `addTaskErr.style.display = '';`
2. When new task is added as a initial step I'm hiding the error text
    `addTaskErr.style.display = 'none';`
3. While preparing the list element I'm adding event listener to the delete button to delete the list and when it clicked. Removing the list element by getting parent element by using `this.parentElement` property.

   ```
   `link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        this.parentElement.remove();
        e.preventDefault();
      });`
   ```

**Sample Code**

```js
    var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput'),
        taskList = document.getElementById('taskList'),
        addTaskErr = document.getElementById('addTaskError');
        //_localStorage = localStorage,
        //counter = 0;
        
    function addTask(e) {
      if(taskInput.value === '') {            
        addTaskErr.style.display = '';
      } else {
        addTaskErr.style.display = 'none';
        // Creat li Element
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        // Add class
        li.className = 'collection-item';
        // Create Text Node and Append to li
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
        // Create new link element
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        // Add Class
        link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
        // Add Icon HTML
        link.innerHTML = '<span class="fa fa-remove">X</span>'
        // Append Link To li
        li.appendChild(link);
        
        link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
           this.parentElement.remove();
           //counter--;
           e.preventDefault();
        });
        //counter++;
        // Append li to ul
        taskList.appendChild(li);

        //console.log(li);

        // Store task in Local Storage
        storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInput.value);

        // Clear The Input
        taskInput.value = '';
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    function storeTaskInLocalStorage(value){
     
      /*_localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(taskLists));*/
    }
```

```css
.fa.fa-remove{
  padding:4px 6px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color:red;
  margin-left:5px;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

li{
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border:1px solid #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="taskInput"/>
      <button onclick="addTask(event)">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span id="addTaskError" style="color:red; display:none;">
        Please enter a task
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ol id="taskList">
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation why the OP had the problem they described, and how this code resolves that?

Comment: Hey anil, this is great and what I am looking for  so thank you. Please can you explain a little bit about what you have done to help me understand, I am sort of new to JS so trying to fully understand your solution will really help me.

Comment: @trincot Is this explanation is fine.

Comment: @Nav, Did you understand my explanation? If it is full fill you are requirement then accept the answer. So, that other person will not check they will use there time on other question.

Comment: @AnilTalla I do in some ways, few things: what do you mean by, "Because you're always checking value is initial or not, If value initial then you are directly showing message and also not removing it when task added". What is initial? Also how does the counter know the length of the list?

Comment: With this code if you add a task, the next time you try and click `Add` with an empty input box, it will not show any error. Are you sure this is what the OP wanted?

Comment: @Nav, Initial means empty. You are using if condition `taskInput.value === ''`.

Comment: @ChatterOne, I modified code now. It will show error messages when add button clicked with empty input value.

Comment: @AnilTalla Your explanation is now different from what your code does. You increase and decrease `counter` but don't check it. Also, your code is basically the same as OP, which leads to the conclusion that the problem is elsewhere. Specifically not in the function but in how it's being called.

Comment: Thanks for this guys, I will add the code to how addTask() is being called in a few hours when I am home. Maybe you can see then further information...

Comment: @ChatterOne, I modified my explanation. Can you check it. You can suggest me if any changes are required.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but here is how the function is being called:

`loadEventListeners();`

`function loadEventListeners() {
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
}`